# In vagrant, there is two virtual machine with the same name

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

[image]

I use vagrant, but i don't know why there is two virtual machine with the same name, just differ in id(number after name) i.e. in case of this pic, 1445839840601_4522

i guess it may the result of running 'vagrant provision'

how can i boot with another version?

Answer (score 0):

run `vagrant global-status` to get the list of all VMs with their Ids and the directory they have been created

```
fhenri@machine:~$ vagrant global-status
id       name    provider      state       directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
d17e2f2  default vmware_fusion not running /Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/testbox.puppet
371e3b4  default vmware_fusion not running /Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/centos
678add8  default vmware_fusion not running /Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu
716d724  default vmware_fusion not running /Volumes/AribaVM/T@C
7384c9e  default vmware_fusion not running /Volumes/Passport/education/mongodb/vm
7d51e32  default vmware_fusion not running /Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/testbox.puphpet
adf884c  db      vmware_fusion not running /Volumes/Transcend/pws.light
2d4f81b  app     vmware_fusion not running /Volumes/Transcend/pws.light
5490b3b  default virtualbox    poweroff    /Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/windows
```

you will be able to retrieve to which project/directory they have been created from